# Mean Value Theorem, find c.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, roots

[image]

The derivative of $\frac1x$ is $\frac{-1}{x^2}$.

How do I find the $c$ if there is no zero in the derivative of the function?

I started with $-1/x^2= -0.0625$ but I'm confused from here on.

Comment: $\frac{-1}{c^2} = -0.0625 \Leftrightarrow c=\sqrt{16}=4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is asking you to solve for

$$f'(c) = -0.0625$$

where $$c \in (2,8)$$

Hence, we need to solve for $$-\frac{1}{c^2}=-0.0625$$

$$c^2=\frac{1}{0.0625}$$

Solve for $c \in (2,8)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f (x)=\frac {1}{x} $$
$f $ is continuous at $[2,8] $ and differentiable at $(2,8) $ thus by MVT,
$$\exists c\in (2,8)  : $$
$$f (8)-f (2)=(8-2)f'(c)$$
$$\frac {1}{8}-\frac {1}{2}=-6.\frac {1}{c^2} $$

$$\frac {-6}{16}=\frac {-6}{c^2} $$
$$\implies c=4$$